# Conditional formatting with multiple criteria for one cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I have 5 cells (A1:E1) that are filled with either 'yes', 'no', or 'maybe'.
Can I have conditional formatting on F1, where if 'yes' is green, and if 'no' is red?

To clarify:

```
=countif({a1:e1};"yes")
```

can format my last field for a green, but is there way to have that, but in addition format for ANY in A1:E1="no" then format for red instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can but its unclear if you need that for whole range or just for one ocurance so the answer depends...

but this are the custom formulas in conditional formatting in **F1**:

```
=countif({a1;b1;c1;d1;e1};"yes")
=countif({a1;b1;c1;d1;e1};"no")
```

Comment: Why not just `a1:e1`?

Comment: Sorry I was being vague. 
"=countif({a1;b1;c1;d1;e1};"yes")"  or "=countif({a1:e1};"yes")" does work, But is there a was to say =countif({a1:e1};"yes") but if ANY in A1:E1="no" then format for red

Comment: @Frysynberg then just switch them that 1tst will be `=countif({a1:e1};"no")` this way you will get what you need.